# 404 on Properly mapped SpringBoot RestController

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, controller

I'm experiencing a little issue that is wasting a lot of my time...

I've created, for demonstration purposes, a simple SpringBoot application using the Eclipse New > Spring Starter Project.

Here is my Application class:

```
package it.asirchia;

//All needed imports

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static HashMap<Long,Book> books = new HashMap<Long, Book>();
    public static HashMap<Long,Editor> editors = new HashMap<Long, Editor>();
    public static HashMap<Long,Person> authors = new HashMap<Long, Person>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then I've created the *EditorsApis* Controller:

```
package it.asirchia.apis;

//All needed imports

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/editors")
public class EditorsApis {

    private static long counter = 0;

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public HashMap<Long, Editor> getAllEditor(){
        return Application.editors;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void postNewEditor(@RequestBody Editor editor){
        Application.editors.put(counter++, editor);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{editorid}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void updateEditor(@PathVariable long editorid,
                                @RequestBody Editor editor){
        Application.editors.put(editorid, editor);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{editorid}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Editor getEditor(@PathVariable long editorid){
        return Application.editors.get(editorid);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{editorid}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteEditor(@PathVariable long editorid){
        Application.editors.remove(editorid);
    }

}
```

And an *AuthorsApis* and a *BooksApis* controllers that are very similar to the *EditorApis* one.

Of course I've created too all the three Pojos:
**Editor.class**, **Person.class** and **Book.class**

I've started up the Eclipse embedded Spring runtime and I can see that all the paths are properly mapped:

> INFO [main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping Mapped "
>    {[/authors/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.HashMap it.asirchia.apis.AuthorsApis.getAllAuthors()

And so on and so forth for all the other Rest APIs I've implemented.
The last three lines of the log are:

> Starting beans in phase 0
>
> Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
>
> Started Application in 5.547 seconds (JVM running for 6.169)

Ok, for me wverything is properly configured, up and running. But when I try to invoke

```
GET /authors HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
```

I obtain:

```
{
"timestamp": 1507286437765,
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/authors"
}
```

And the same happens for **ALL** the REST APIs I've implemented.
Any idea about the reason of this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Try localhost:8080/editors/ or localhost:8080/authors/ . It should work

Comment: I tried... It doesn't work

Comment: Sorry @VelNaga With the trailing slash it worked...
Thank you

Comment: could you add your application.properties?

Comment: @Cyril my application.properties is empty.

Comment: @VelNaga please add you comment as response and I'll accept it

Comment: @sirnino Thanks.I am doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following mapping will work **localhost:8080/authors/** for you.Since in your method mapping GET you have added the "/" so you should provide the trailing slash in URL also. If you want mapping like this **localhost:8080/authors** then follow the below code,

```
@RequestMapping(value={"","/"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public HashMap<Long, Editor> getAllEditor(){
    return Application.editors;
}
```

The above will accept,

1)  localhost:8080/editors

2)  localhost:8080/editors/

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -2):

Can you just try to add a action content in value.Here only specifying only a "/".Like

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/updateEditor", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

If you need to add any path variable,you can modify the same with following,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updateEditor/{editorid}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
```

Just try this method also.